# Self-entity relationship in Entity framework - Error while saving

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, savechanges

I have an Employee entity, which is having following properties:

- EmployeeId
- EmployeeName
- EmployeeManagerId
- EmployeeManager

All above fields can be mapped with a table in database, except, EmployeeManager.

It is declared as

```
public virtual Employee EmployeeManager { get; set; }
```

When I try to save a new Employee in database, it is giving me an error saying EmployeeManager_EmployeeId field does not exist in database, whereas, I believe this should not at all be part of INSERT operation.

How to deal with this kind of situation.

Any help on this much appreciated.

Thanks

Nirman

Comment: What exactly are you saving and how is your relation with EmployeeManager defined?

Comment: I have not defined relation with EmployeeManager as such.